# How to register Google Calendar Push Notification when authenticating with username/password

Tags: push-notification, google-calendar-api

I wrote a server side application that access a specific Google Calendar. Unlike most services out there that access visitors' calendars using OAuth2.0 proxy authentication, my application needs to access my calendar. Therefore I am using username/password authentication on the server.
Now I need to register calendar push notifications to call a web hook when the calendar is updated. All the examples I found are using access token, which I can't get from username/password authentication.
1. Is there a way to register a calendar web hook not through API but rather from some service?
2. Is it possible to get access token based on username/password authentication?
3. Is there an API to register a web hook on google calendar using username/password?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

So far I know what you want is not possible. My I suggest that you use [OAuth with a refresh token](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer#refresh) on your server side application. You'll just have to grant your application access to your calendar once and your server will be able to access your calendar until you or it revokes access.